# How to save Gulp bundle in the source directory?

Tags: gulp

I am following the [Fast browserify builds with watchify recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md) and get it working, but would like my bundles to be written to the original source folder.

For example, I have the following code (taken directly from the recipe, but modified slightly)

```
// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
    entries: glob.sync("./dev/www/**/*-root.js"),
    debug: true
};
var opts = _.assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts)); 



gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal


function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
        .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })) // loads map from browserify file
    // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
        .pipe(gulp.dest((file) => {return file.base;}));
        //.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
```

as you can see in the `entries: glob.sync("./dev/www/**/*-root.js"),` line, I am scanning for multiple files to be bundled.

The problem I am encountering is the `.pipe(gulp.dest((_file: any) => {return file.base;}));` line, which returns the root project folder's path, not the original source folder's path.

How can I obtain the source folder path for writing to?

#### Edit

I found http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/  which describes how to create multiple bundles, but it doesn't use watchify.   it looks like this issue might be a limitation of vinyl-source-stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a lot of effort, but I figured out a solution.

Generally I followed the pattern found at http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/  but added caching of each browserify object created (one per page) plus added watchify to it.

Other things added in the following code:

- livereload
- dev server launch
- typescript (tsx) compile (including chained sourcemaps)

full solution (typescript code):

```
import gulp = require("gulp");
import browserify = require("browserify");
var watchify = require("watchify");

import source = require("vinyl-source-stream");

import buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");


import gutil = require("gulp-util");
import sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var sourcemapsApply = require("vinyl-sourcemaps-apply");

import _ = require("lodash");


import glob = require("glob");
import vinyl = require("vinyl");


import rename = require("gulp-rename");

var minifyify = require("minifyify");

import path = require("path");

var tsify = require("tsify");


var livereload = require("gulp-livereload");
var notify = require("gulp-notify");

var closureCompiler = require("gulp-closure-compiler");

import uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
import http = require("http");
var st = require("st");  //module for serving static files.  used to create dev server.   https://www.npmjs.com/package/st

var eventStream = require("event-stream"); //module for merging multiple vinyl streams to return one when finishing task.   see http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/

var rootPath = __dirname;

gulp.task("default", () => {
    gulp.start("tsxDevWatch");
});


gulp.task("devServer", (done) => {

    var rootPath = __dirname;
    //start server
    http.createServer(st({
        path: rootPath,
        index: true, //"index.html",
        cache: false,
    })).listen(8080,"localhost", done);

});

gulp.task("tsxDevWatch",["devServer"], () => {



    livereload.listen();

    //browserify+watchify of *-main.js files and compiles into *-main.bundle.js files IN SAME FOLDER

    //created mostly following the pattern described here: http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/
    //but adds stupid source-filepath workaround for use with "source" (vinyl-source-stream needed for watchify)

    /** the files we are going to browserify bundle*/
    var entries = glob.sync("./dev/www/**/*-main.tsx", {
        realpath: true, //so paths are absolute.  This is required so our "bMaps" mappings stay intact, because watchify.on("update") always provides full filepath, 
    });
    /** we create one browserify instance for each file we are bundling.  this caches the browserify instance so it can be reused on watchify updates (decreasing compile time by A LOT) */
    var bMaps: { [key: string]: BrowserifyObject } = {};

    var tasks = entries.map((entry) => {    
        process.chdir(path.dirname(entry));

        var browserifyOptions = {
            entries: [entry],
            debug: true,
            plugin: [
                watchify,
                //tsify,
            ],
            cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true // Requirement of watchify
        };
        var b = browserify(browserifyOptions);


        b.plugin(tsify, { //options from here: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig
            jsx: "react",
            //inlineSourceMap: false,  //sourcemap options don't seem to matter, seems to be set by browserify or something.
            //sourceMap:true,
            module: "commonjs",
            target: "es5",
        });

        bMaps[entry] = b;

        b.on('update', (updatedFiles: string[]) => {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n UPDATE CALLED FOR", JSON.stringify(updatedFiles));

            var rebuildAll = false;
            _.forEach(updatedFiles, (updatedFile) => {
                if (bMaps[updatedFile] == null) {
                    //a dependency needs to be rebuilt, skip rebuilding anything that changed and do EVERYTHING
                    rebuildAll = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (rebuildAll === false) {
                _.forEach(updatedFiles, (updatedFile) => {
                    console.log(" ============= update()", updatedFile);
                    //find the b for this file
                    var _b = bMaps[updatedFile];
                    //do a bundle for it
                    _createTsXBundle(_b, updatedFile);

                });
            } else {
                //this is a dependency, rebuild EVERYTHING!!!
                _.forEach(bMaps, (value_b, key_entry) => {
                    _createTsXBundle(value_b, key_entry);
                });
            }

        }); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
        b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

        return _createTsXBundle(b, entry);
    });

    return eventStream.merge.apply(null, tasks);
});

/** worker to create a tsx bundle.  used by a task  */
function _createTsXBundle(b: BrowserifyObject, entry: string) {
    process.chdir(path.dirname(entry));
    console.log("================= doBundle()", entry);

    var bundledStream = b.bundle();
    bundledStream = <any>bundledStream.on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'));

    var currentSource: vinyl;

    var targetName = path.basename(entry, ".tsx") + ".bundle.js";
    bundledStream
        .pipe(source(targetName))
        .pipe(buffer()) //need this to support chaining our vinyl source file

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    //// optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    //  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
    //      loadMaps: true,
    //      //debug: true
    //  })) // loads map from browserify file

    /////////////////////////  WORKS, BUT NEED TO ENABLE SOURCEMAPS plugin TO GET SOURCEMAPS
    //// uglify
    //.pipe(uglify({
    //  //preserveComments: "all",              
    //  output:<any> {
    //      max_line_len: 300,
    //      //screw_ie8: false,
    //      //beautify: true,
    //      //comments: true,
    //      //bracketize: true,
    //      //quote_keys: true,
    //      //width: 120,
    //      //semicolons:true,
    //  },
    //  compress: {
    //      unsafe:true,
    //  },
    //}))

    //// Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    //  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())

        .pipe(gulp.dest((file: vinyl) => {
            //console.log("GULP.DEST(file)\n base=", file.base, "\n cwd=", file.cwd, "\n path=", file.path, "\n relative=", file.relative);
            return file.base;
        }))
        .pipe(livereload())

    ;

    return bundledStream;
}
```

Comment: If you don't need sourcemaps, this solution is overkill.   (you don't need to chdir)   and if you do need sourcemaps this solution doesn't work if your bundled files are in multiple directories   (browserify or tsify doesn't setup the sourcemap relative folders properly)

so if you need sourcemaps, best to have 1 gulp file per folder.